# Can a motherboard BIOS profile be used to disable devices?

Tags: bios, profile

Can a mobo BIOS profile be used to disable devices?

I want to have a RAID configuration on two drives, but then I have a non-RAID IDE drive I also want to boot from.  My idea is to have two different profiles.  One profile will have the two RAID SATA drives enabled but keep the IDE drive disabled.  My other profile will enable the IDE drive but keep the two RAID drives disabled.

My thinking is that I can then boot my XP PRO system in IDE mode and not bother with trying to install the RAID drivers on it.

My mobo is ASUS P8Z68-V LX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this,well you cant have different bios profiles, but you can change the boot order each time if you really want to, but it is a bit of a strange way of doing it, you would be far better off with a boot menu to select which OS you want to start.